# Is there a way to set "imagePullPolicy" for Cloud Run Service?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I would like to be able to automatically update my Google Cloud Run Services once my image has been updated on Google Container Registry.

I need to update multiple Cloud Run services based on the same image (which has a tag of :latest ), so I expected this to work.

```
  # build & push the container image
- name: "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest"
  args: ["--cache=true", "--cache-ttl=48h", "--destination=gcr.io/project/titan:latest"]
```

Currently, my titan image gets updated but no new Revision is deployed to Cloud Run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Cloud Run does not automatically deploy a revision when you push a new image to a tag reference. There are many good reasons it doesn’t.

When a Cloud Run revision is deployed, it computes the sha256 hash of the image reference.

Therefore when you specify a container image with `:latest` tag, Cloud Run uses its sha256 reference to deploy and scale out that revision of your service. When you update `:latest` tag to point to the new image, Cloud Run will still use the previous image. It would be a dangerous and slippery slope otherwise.

If you need to auto-deploy new revisions to Cloud Run based on a new image push, I recommend two solutions:

1. Make “gcloud beta run deploy” command a step in your Google Cloud Build process. (easy) https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment
2. Write a GCF/Run service that deploys your app to Cloud Run every time there’s a new image pushed by subscribing to Google Cloud Build (or GCR) notifications through PubSub. (much harder)

Comment: "Google Cloud Run does not automatically deploy a revision when you push a new image to a tag reference....It would be a dangerous and slippery slope otherwise." can you elaborate on this? Automatic deployments seem like they should naturally exist.

Comment: I don't see where I can add “gcloud beta run deploy” as a setp. Do I need to [set up continuous deployment manually](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run)?

Comment: @ahmet Is there any solution for this problem from Google side recently ?

Comment: FYI: "When a Cloud Run revision is deployed, it computes the sha256 hash of the image reference." does not seem to be true for Cloud Run **Jobs**. I just tested this (i.e. use a tag instead of a SHA hash for the image and pushed a new image between executions) and the next execution used the new image instead of the old one. I couldn't find an official statement in the docs, though.

Comment: Ummm, no. You can do it in Kubernetes, and Cloud Run is based on k8s, clearly. You can set imagePullPolicy: Always or IfNotPresent. Again Google is imposing their opinions on everyone else, and not allowing the user to decide. That, dear Google, is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The default pull policy is `IfNotPresent` which causes the `Kubelet` to skip pulling an image if it already exists. If you would like to always force a pull, you can do one of the following:

- set the imagePullPolicy of the container to Always.
- omit the imagePullPolicy and use :latest as the tag for the image to use.
- omit the imagePullPolicy and the tag for the image to use.
- enable the [AlwaysPullImages](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#alwayspullimages) admission controller.

Note that you should avoid using :latest tag, see [Best Practices for Configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images) for more information.

For example, creating a YAML file `dummy.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: whatever
      image: index.docker.io/DOCKER_USER/PRIVATE_REPO_NAME:latest
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command: [ "echo", "SUCCESS" ]
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey
```

Then run:

```
kubectl create -f dummy.yaml
```

Comment: This is not a Kubernetes question.

Comment: Oh yes, this is my bad. I am very sorry!

Comment: @LeKhiem, please delete the answer.

Comment: Don't delete the answer. This is good. This is how Google Cloud should behave as it is based on Kubernetes. They should allow the user to decide on imagePullPolicy, and leave default to IfNotPresent as many would believe that to be the safer practice (I have no problem with that position). People need to wake up and realize that Google should not impose their politics on users. Google Cloud is clearly geared to large enterprises with unlimited cash, not small individual developers.